# How to keep two databases with different schemas up-to-date

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

Our company has really old legacy system with such a bad database design (no foreign keys, columns with serialized PHP arrays, etc. :(). We decided to rewrite a system from a scratch with new database schema.

We want to rewrite a system by parts. So we will split old monolithic application to many smaller ones.

Problem is: we want to have live data in two databases. Old and New schema.
I'd like to ask you if anyone of you knows best practices how to do this.

What we think of:

1. asynchronous data synchronization with message queue
2. make a REST API in new system and make legacy application to use
       it instead of db calls
3. some kind of table replication

Thank you very much

Comment: Does the old system at least have primary keys (or surrogates) ?

Comment: @joop Yes. There are primary keys

Comment: Keep these PKs, and refer to them in the new database. This could be directly, or indirectly, via an extra layer of indirection, like data-vault.

Comment: @joop I will do that, but how can I synchronize the data between this databases when legacy application has to be running (we need to keep business running) and parts of new system needs to be running on different database?

Comment: Well since the *new* system has the keys, these keys can be used to update (or create) the new system (periodically), like in ETL.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with a similar problem in the past. There was a system which didn't have support but there was people using it because, It had some features (security holes) which allowed them certain functionalities. However, they also needed new functionalities.

I selected the tables which involved the new system and I created some triggers for cross update the tables, so when I created a register on the old system the trigger created a copy in the new system and reversal. If you design this system properly you would have both systems working at the same time in real time.

The drawback is that while the both system are running the system is going to become slower since you have to maintain the integrity of two databases in every operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would *start* by adding a database layer to accept API calls from the business layer, then write to both the old schema and the new.  This adds complexity *up front*, but it lets you guarantee that the data stays in sync.

This would require changing the legacy system to call an API instead of issuing SQL statements.  If they did not have the foresight to do that originally, you may not be able to take my approach.  But, you should do it going forward.

Triggers may or may not work out.  In older versions of MySQL, there can be only one trigger of a given type on a given table.  This forces you to lump unrelated things into a single trigger.

Replication can solve *some* changes -- Engine, datatypes, etc.  But it cannot help with splitting one table into two.  Be careful of the replication of Triggers and where the Trigger has effect (between Master and Slave).  *In general*, a stored routine should be performed on the Master, letting the effect be replicated to the slave.  But it may be worth considering how to have the trigger run in the Slave instead.  Or different triggers in the two servers.

Another thought is to do the transformation in stages.  By careful planning of schema changes versus application of triggers versus code changes versus database layer, you can do partial transformations one at a time, sometimes without having a big outage to update everything simultaneously (with your fingers crossed).  A simple example:  (1) change code to dynamically handle either new or old schema, (2) change the schema, (3) clean up the code (remove handling of old schema).

Answer (score 0):

Doing a database migration may be a tedious task considering the complexity of data and structure of the tables which is of-course with out any constraints or a proper design. But given that your legacy application was doing its job - the amount of corrupt usable data will be minimal.

For the said problem I would suggest a db migration task which would convert all the old legacy data into the new form. And develop the new application. The advantages being.

1) There is not need to keep 2 different applications.

2) No need to change the code in the legacy application - which can become messy.

3) DB migration will give us a chance to correct any corrupt data (if needed).

DB migration may not be practical under all scenarios but if you can do it in lesser effort than making the changes for database sync, new api's for legacy application - I would suggest to go for it.